# Ie ignore javascript files or code in general

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In css when you want something to be ie only you can comment it out and assign ie. I have a jquery plugin that breaks in IE I don't want it to run in ie but I want it to run in all other browsers. How can I do this?

**this worked!**

```
jQuery(function() {
if(jQuery.browser.msie){}
else
{$('.div').corner("round 20px");};
});
```

Comment: Well, the best solution would be to check why your plugin is not working in IE...

Comment: it's a rounded corner plugin with stroke just icky in iE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some form of browser checking code that wraps your code in an if statement and only selectively runs it.

Psuedo code:

```
if( browse != "IE" )
{
     ... run code that breaks in IE ...
}
```

Or you could possibly wrap it in side of a `try`/`catch` block

Comment: this worked! thanks

jQuery(function() {
if(jQuery.browser.msie){}
else
{$('.div').corner("round 20px");};
});

Comment: @ThomasReggi, if this is the correct answer, please use the tick and mark this as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using conditional comments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

```
<!--[if !IE]>
Special instructions for non IE browsers
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) to check the browser and version. However, it is discouraged by the manual because it's bad practice to check only the browser name. It's much better to track down what feature in the browser is breaking the plugin and then check for that feature only with [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) or similar.